# How to find the value changes of subviews of UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a UIView which contains multiple UITextFields, UIButtons, and I need to know any of those subviews values are changed or not. That is for example, in case of UITextFields, there is a function like textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField. This function will get notify us if there is any change in the text of any UITextFields. Like, is there any method to get notify if any of the subviews in UIVIew has value change? Please help me.

Comment: specify which kind of subview do u need to observe? is it custom UIView class or something like UISwitch or UISlider?

Comment: Like UITextFields, UIButton

Comment: if u want to observe all the changes that being made inside that subview, you might have to specify the types and observe all of them and delegate back to the main view, there's no 1 line way to do this

Comment: Okey thank you @Tj3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **tag** for both buttons and textFields and easily identify which textField's value has been changed using tag. As for example,as your textField is the subView of a UIView you can retrieve text from specific textField just like this.

```
NSString *text = ((UITextField*)[YourView viewWithTag:result]).text;
```

And for button maintain one buttonAction for allButtons and grab button click using tag.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if(sender.tag == 1) {
            //Do something.
      }    
}
```

Comment: No no, Actually i need to know any of the subviews value/ states has been changed or not. For example  i have view, which contains UITextFields, UIButtons, UISwitch etc.., when updating that view, i need to is there is any change that i made in the view or not. That is changing any UITextFields value or clicks on any button something like that.